# constraint layout performance as recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

ConstraintLayout version: 1.1.0 stable.

I am using ConstraintLayout as recyclerview item layout, xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg_selector"
    android:minHeight="60dp">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/left_guide_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/top_guide_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="10dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/right_guide_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="16dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/bottom_guide_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="7dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/common_head_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guide_line"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tv_unread_red_point"
        style="@style/tips_red_dot_circle_common"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/avatar"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_unread_msg_count"
        style="@style/tips_red_dot_num_common"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guide_line"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/avatar"
        tools:text="99+"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>

    <cn.test.widget.NickWidget
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/msg"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/time"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_guide_line"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        style="@style/text_h3_common_36px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/def_value"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guide_line"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/name"
        tools:text="11:22"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/msg_state"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/recent_msg_state"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/msg"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/icon_chatroom"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/msg"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_chatroom"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/common_head_icon"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/msg"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/msg_state"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/msg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/msg"
        app:layout_goneMarginLeft="10dp"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        style="@style/text_h2_common_42px"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_guide_line"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/icon_chatroom"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/chat_room_exit_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_goneMarginLeft="10dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chat_room_exit_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/im_icon_chat_room_exit"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/msg"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/msg"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/group_msg_not_notify_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/msg"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/group_msg_not_notify_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/pub_nngroup_icon_shield"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/msg"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/chat_room_exit_icon"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_guide_line"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/msg"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

We got really bad performance when scrolling through the RecyclerView, and everything work just fine if I change item layout from a ConstraintLayout to a traditional layout (Nesting 4 or 5 layers). What can we do about this?

Comment: what issue you found on scrolling with CL ??

Comment: Yes, `ConstraintLayout` is slow. Don't use it.

Comment: Could you also paste you adapter code? This may have nothing to do with your layout at all.

Comment: I've the same problem, also this performance problem seems not to appear in older version of Android

Answer (score 0):

I have used ConstraintLayout as item layout of recyclerview, it **scrolls smoothly**. I think there is no problem of ConstraintLayout, but make sure that you should not call **`myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`** in adapter class. It will make your app slow UI rendering.

Refer this [**Android document for Slow rendering**](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render.html)

Comment: Could you please post you item layout here? Maybe I use it in a wrong way. maybe we should not put too much item in a single ConstraintLayout? Or could you just run my code on your device as recyclerview item and check it out.